# Which files are the faulty ones when checking defects

Tags: system-installation, usb

I am trying to install ubuntu from USB stick. When selecting "check disk for defects", it reports "Check finished: errors found in 2 files". Is there way to see what are the 2 defect files? If I knew that I could make an educated decision whether I proceed with the installation or not.

PS this question may be somewhat duplicate with some earlier questions but the answers to those tend to be on different issue (md5sum etc). My md5sum does match and this is the fourth USB stick I am trying

Answer (score 6):

If the md5checksum checks out I would assume it is safe to continue. It could be the USB that could be faulty.

Possible method to confirm: re-download the ISO and burn it again to this and another USB or even use another machine and burn it there to this and another USB. And recheck for md5sum and for errors.

> Is there way to see what are the 2 defect files?

I have not seen one yet (but would like to be proven wrong ;) )

The command it runs

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz  boot=casper integrity-check
iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash --
```

It should be possible to run `integrity-check  iso-scan/filename=${iso_path}` against your ISO and see if it shows any messages regarding the files it errors out on.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer by myself. See https://askubuntu.com/a/547369/114489 i.e. navigate to the usb drive and run md5sum -c md5sum.txt