# get Ubuntu 18.04 on a USB stick

Tags: 18.04

I have a slow Internet connection, so to download Ububtu 18.04 would take several days!  In March I think I saw Canonical (?) offering 18.04 on a USB key, but now they say it is not available on a USB key. does anyone know where 18.04 can be bought on a USB stick?
( ? )

Answer (score 0):

[Canonical does not offer bootable USB/CDs any more](https://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17).

However there's plenty of results on eBay for Ubuntu USB drives and CDs for pretty cheap. Keep in mind some security updates and non-free packages are quite large to download.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bummer.  It looks like it is true that Canonical Store no longer has [Bootable USB stick](https://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17) as an option.

This doesn't make a lot of sense to me, as I see people with limited Internet access as part of Ubuntu 's target audience.  Maybe with more people needing it, they'll change their minds.

Otherwise, regardless of the source (Canonical DVD/USB, eBay, your mom), you should **check the disc hash** against those provided by Canonical to [ensure the integrity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547332/can-an-integrity-check-be-run-against-a-usb-boot-disk).  It's very important that you do this with the disk first.

Can you find access to a 2Mb/s line, and two hours of time?  Ubuntu 18.04 `iso` is 1.8GB.

If you're really out of the way, your best bet may be downloading from a closer server geographically, and using a client that supports resume.  Using `.torrent` could be ideal, especially if you build or are part of any sort of network in which other have or need the data.  For example, because of your situation, you may actually set something up for other people in your area to be able to get the updates.  If you and a friend both download on your own connections, but share a different, local connection, then you could improve the speed by peering with your friend.  For example, if you're using Satellite, Cellular or some other mobile connection, or live close enough to your friend.

Depending on your location, you could try Linux or technology meetups, and see if there are others there who have better access, and who are willing to provide a CD/USB.  Sometimes libraries or other places with Internet access will provide Linux distributions, or free access to them.